# How can I best loop out this xpath expression from a comma separated list?

Tags: php, xpath

I have multiple 'PINs' as I'll call them, stored in a input field in a comma separated format. So these are stored as a string in the format `'1234,5678'`.

I can already get xPath to filter an XML file for a single value by using this:

```
xpath("/ReaderDetails/Reader[Pin=1234]")
```

I'm trying to find a simple way to take the comma separated string, and interpret into the xpath expression so I can use multiple values.

The intended outcome will be:

```
xpath("/ReaderDetails/Reader[Pin='1234' or Pin='5678']")
```

It's important, that this should be able to handle as many PINs as are entered in the input field.

So far I'm able to put the PINs into an array using `array_map('trim', explode(',', get_option('dream_team_readers')))` but can't figure out how to create the expression as needed above.

Comment: it might be the pipe `|` character you need...

Comment: No, I' already know what format I need, it's not the xpath expression I'm asking about, it's the PHP loop to build it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You ought, perhaps, to be able to accomplish the desired string pattern like this@

```
# to emulate the array of PINS...
$pins=[ 1234,3245,5423,4353,64576,5675,2347,3453 ];


$tmp=[];
foreach( $pins as $pin )$tmp[]=sprintf( 'Pin="%d"', $pin );
$expr=sprintf( '/ReaderDetails/Reader[ %s ]', implode( ' or ', $tmp ) );
```

If you were to print the resultant `$expr` variable you would get:

```
/ReaderDetails/Reader[ Pin="1234" or Pin="3245" or Pin="5423" or Pin="4353" or Pin="64576" or Pin="5675" or Pin="2347" or Pin="3453" ]
```